# Creating Vegetable Mix Analog

Tags: soil, compost, peat

I have quite a lot of potting mix and compost, but no unused topsoil or similar.   I do, however, have access to a large quantity of used cocopeat blocks (they were used to grow Courgettes, and before that eggplants)

Is it feasible to mix compost with the cocopeat from the cocopeat blocks and use that as a vegetable mix ?   Should I add some slow release fertilizer granules to it as well ?

Not sure exactly what I want to grow yet, but they will be winter vegetables or leafy greens - which i'm going to throw into a .5m^2 plastic sandpit with holes drilled in the bottom.

(If the above is not feasible, I also have quite a lot of bark chips - I assume that mixing these with compost would not be as good ?)

Comment: why not just use the potting mix only?  And drill the holes 2 inches above the bottom to give yourself a water reservoir.

Comment: I had no idea that would work - I assumed - from the information I've gleaned from Garden stores - that potting mix was to heavy for the water to drain through properly.  (I've already drilled holes in the bottom of the sandpit - not sure how much difference that makes to your statement either)

Comment: Also, I have some potting mix, but a lot of compost - I was hoping to use that instead - in fairness, I did not realise there was a huge difference - I now suspect i'm wrong there !

Comment: compost is not guaranteed to be weed/seeds free.  It may have dirt in it or it may not depending on how it's made.  It's a soil amendment, not a soil replacement.

Comment: Potting mix is designed for use in containers, so it is supposed to drain.  It likely has pumice or vermiculite to help it drain.

Comment: Be wary of adding too much organic matter that is not well composted to container plants. It often causes fungal growth that attracts soil gnats - this especially applies to applies to stuff like coffee grounds or tea leaves. If you do make sure you have a covering such as sand or rocks.

Comment: Are you intending to grow the vegetables indoors or outdoors?

Comment: @max - thank you - im using it in a polytunnel.